# How can I use leave-one-out cross-validation on loess function?

Tags: r

I'm getting NA as my result. What am I doing wrong?

```
data(Boston, package='MASS')

x <- Boston$dis
y <- Boston$nox
n <- length(x)
cvs <- rep(0, n)

for(i in 1:n){
 xi <- x[-i]
 yi <- y[-i]
 d <- loess(yi~xi, span=0.2, degree=2)
 cvs[i] <- (y[i] - predict(d, newdata=data.frame(xi=x[i])))^2
}

mean(cvs)
```

Comment: Hint: In the editor window, mark the code and hit Ctrl+K to indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mean(cvs,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0.003753745

plot(y~x)
lines( d$x[order(d$x)], d$fitted[order(d$x)])
which(is.na(d$fitted[order(d$x)]) )
#integer(0)
```

You can see that the NA's come at the extremes of the x-range:

```
#add as debugging code
if(is.na(cvs[i]) ) {print(i);print(x[i])}}
[1] 354
[1] 12.1265
[1] 373
[1] 1.1296

 range(x)
#[1]  1.1296 12.1265
```

But I still don't understand why:

```
(y[ which(is.na(cvs)) ]-predict(d, x[ which(is.na(cvs)) ] ))^2
[1] 3.218139e-06 3.742504e-04
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate functions such as `mean` do not allow `NA` values by default, but you have some in the result vector:

```
which(is.na(cvs))
## [1] 354 373
```

Not sure where they come from, but you could make the `mean` function accept `NA` values by passing `na.rm=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `loess.control(surface = "direct")` in order to extrapolate.

You also may want to find a faster way to do this, since this requires a lot of fitting.